# "Permission denied: Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission. (mapped-IPv4)" while accessing geocode URL

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-geocoding-api

I'm use google geocode api.
My code is:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude+"&key="+server key"); 

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

But i'm getting below error:

> **Exception message : Permission denied: Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission. (mapped-IPv4)**

The same code works very well locally, the Appengine account is a paid account.

Please give me solution..

Comment: How/where are you accessing maps in both cases?

Comment: Did you only authorize `localhost` when you configured your app?

Comment: we dont have any configartion requried..

Comment: Based from this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/VBxmG1wdHSg), try to check your configuration because maybe it was connecting to 127.0.0.1 instead of the correct production IP. It appears that it is connecting to a local database while developing (127.0.0.1) and then attempted to deploy, but still the deployed code tried to reach "127.0.0.1" which fails in the production network.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this most Google IPs are blocked on GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions).

> Private, broadcast, multicast, and Google IP ranges (except those whitelisted below), are blocked

Answer (score 0):

I Got Answer:

```
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude+"&key="+EnvirnomentConstant.GEO_LOCATION_KEY);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        String result = IOUtils.toString((conn.getInputStream()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);



        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map = objectMapper.readValue(result, Map.class);
        List<Map<String, Object>> countries = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> countries1 = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        countries = (List<Map<String, Object>>) map.get("results");
        for (Map<String, Object> countryMap : countries){
            if(countryMap.get("types").toString().contains("country")){
                countries1 = (List<Map<String, Object>>) countryMap.get("address_components");
                for (Map<String, Object> countryMap1 : countries1){
                    countryName =  countryMap1.get("long_name").toString();
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
        m_ObjLog.warning("countryName: "+countryName);
        return countryName;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        ErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        return null;
    }
```